# Perforce Labels : Does perforce allow diff across labels in different branches

Tags: perforce

I have to perform a Perforce Labelling . I wanted to know if the following is possible .

Branch 1 : It was labelled as Label1 and then Label2 . 
I can diff between labels Label1 and Label2

Brach2 : It was labelled as Label3 and then Label4 . 
I can diff between Label3 and Label4

But does perforce allow me to diff across branches ? ex Label1 vs Label3 ??? 
It does not seem to show results in a meaningful manner .
Is this expected ?

Comment: If you can post a screenshot of the diff window so we can see what is not "a meaningful manner". Then we can perhaps help a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://kb.perforce.com/article/43/changes-between-labels

In general you can use the 'diff2' command to diff branches, using whatever revision specifiers you want.  But you'll need to be aware of the label diff caveats described in that KB article.

Comment: Thanks p4-randall .. i was able to get around the problem through trial and error ... Btw thanks for your link . However i use the Perforce Visual Client and not the command line interface . p4V allows my label diffs to be seen really well .